# Facebook Canvas Friend List

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to access my friend's list through Canvas using Javascript to get the birthday of the friend. I am reading the [source documents](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends) and it states that friend's list object only pertains to those individuals that use the app.

Is it possible to get the friend list regardless of if the friend uses the app or not through a Canvas app?

I have tried setting the scope to 'read_friendlists' and changing the api parameter to 'me/friends' and 'me/friendlist'. The array that is returned in empty, and I assume this is because of the aforementioned restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already mentioned, in v2.0 of the Graph API you can only fetch the list of friends that also use the app.

Since v2.0, there is the endpoint `/me/invitable_friends` which is reserved for games that have a mobile **and** a canvas version. It simply returns a list of all friends that you can invite to play your game (thanks Cpt. Obvious). As of today there is no way to get a list of all friends of the user in v2.0 (unless they all use your app ;-)).

In case you are working on a game, you can check out the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends) for the `invitable_friends` edge.

Comment: Would you happen to know how birthdayFB works then? Does is not use the graph API to get this information or is it defaulting to an older version?

Comment: I have no details, but it looks like the app you mentioned was created before the 30th of April and is therefor still able to use v1.0 of the API until it gets shut down on April 30th, 2015